# Get Url match traversing xml simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Here is XML file

```
    <theme name="front">
        <layouts url="/administrator" tpl="default.html" >
            <templates>
                <login url="/login" tpl="login.html"></login>
                <dashboard url="/" tpl="dashboard.html"></dashboard>
                <contact url="/contacts" tpl="contact.html" >
                    <templates>
                        <add url="/add"></add>
                        <edit url="/modify" ></edit>
                        <remove url="/remove" ></remove>
                        <bulk_view url="/bulk-view"></bulk_view>
                    </templates>
                </contact>
                <help url="/help" tpl="content.html"></help>
                <settings url="/settings" tpl="content.html"></settings>
            </templates>
        </layouts>
    </theme>
```

I have two questions:

1. How can i make possible tree urls array like below.

   ```
   /administrator
   /administrator/
   /administrator/login
   /administrator/contacts
   /administrator/contacts/add
   /administrator/contacts/modify
   /administrator/contacts/bulk-view
   /administrator/help
   /administrator/settings
   ```
2. I have a string URL to match like `/administrator/contacts/add`. How can I get SimpleXMLElement Object which matched with this string URL?

Comment: use xpath //*[@url]/@url

Comment: For 2nd xpath `//*[@url="/administrator"]//*[@url="/contacts"]//*[@url="/add"]`

Answer (score 0):

This is best done by *querying* the document for the information you're looking for. For XML this is done best with Xpath.

For example, if you want to get all elements that have an *url* attribute, the query is:

```
//*[@url]
```

And if you now consider to be at *any* of such elements in the document, you can retrieve all *url* attributes in document-order on the *ancestor-or-self* [xpath-axis](https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/xslt/xpath-axes-and-their-shortcuts):

```
ancestor-or-self::*/@url
```

This just for the bare xpath-queries so far. This comes to live when wrapped in PHP code using one of PHP's XML libraries (here exemplary *SimpleXML*)

```
<?php
/**
 * Get Url match traversing xml simplexml_load_file (Example #1)
 *
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/q/31848077/367456
 */
$string = <<<XML
<theme name="front">
    <layouts url="/administrator" tpl="default.html">
        <templates>
            <login url="/login" tpl="login.html"></login>
            <dashboard url="/" tpl="dashboard.html"></dashboard>
            <contact url="/contacts" tpl="contact.html">
                <templates>
                    <add url="/add"></add>
                    <edit url="/modify"></edit>
                    <remove url="/remove"></remove>
                    <bulk_view url="/bulk-view"></bulk_view>
                </templates>
            </contact>
            <help url="/help" tpl="content.html"></help>
            <settings url="/settings" tpl="content.html"></settings>
        </templates>
    </layouts>
</theme>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

foreach ($xml->xpath('//*[@url]') as $urlElement) {
    echo implode("", $urlElement->xpath('ancestor-or-self::*/@url')), "\n";
}
```

The result of that is (also: [online demo](https://eval.in/413844)):

```
/administrator
/administrator/login
/administrator/
/administrator/contacts
/administrator/contacts/add
/administrator/contacts/modify
/administrator/contacts/remove
/administrator/contacts/bulk-view
/administrator/help
/administrator/settings
```

To match any of these URLs, you would need to look if it's the one you're looking for:

```
$search = '/administrator/contacts/add';

foreach ($xml->xpath('//*[@url]') as $urlElement) {
    $url = implode("", $urlElement->xpath('ancestor-or-self::*/@url'));
    if ($url !== $search) {
        continue;
    }
    // found!
    $urlElement->asXML('php://output');
    break;
}
```

Which does output the first element that did match:

```
<add url="/add"/>
```